# white space issue in isAlpha() function of express-validator

Tags: node.js, mongodb, validation, express, express-validator

I am using express-validator in my project
**my json from the client is**

```
{"name": "john doe"}
```

**my express validation code is**

```
[check('name', 'invalid name').isAlpha()]
```

why this code is returning ***invalid name*** while this is a string.
Also I tried **isString()** but it is also not working it is working in the same style as **isAlpha()**.
 Error **json response to the client is**

```
{
"errors": [
    {
        "value": "john doe",
        "msg": "invalid name",
        "param": "name",
        "location": "body"
    }
]
}
```

**does isAlpha() function consider only one word as a string**

**How can I fix this**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the answer. I used custom validation method. It resolved my issue.

```
[check('name').custom((value,{req})=>{
                if(isNaN(value)){
                    return true;
                }else{
                    throw new Error('invalid name')
                }
 })]
```

Answer (score 7):

There is an option of .isAlpha you can use to ignore white spaces:

```
 check('name', 'invalid name').isAlpha('en-US', {ignore: ' '})
```

The first parameter 'en-US' is AlphaLocale. For example I use 'es-ES' to validate Spanish special characters. You can use one of these to validate other languages: 'ar' | 'ar-AE' | 'ar-BH' | 'ar-DZ' | 'ar-EG' | 'ar-IQ' | 'ar-JO' | 'ar-KW' | 'ar-LB' | 'ar-LY' | 'ar-MA' | 'ar-QA' | 'ar-QM' | 'ar-SA' | 'ar-SD' | 'ar-SY' | 'ar-TN' | 'ar-YE' | 'az-AZ' | 'bg-BG' | 'cs-CZ' | 'da-DK' | 'de-DE' | 'el-GR' | 'en-AU' | 'en-GB' | 'en-HK' | 'en-IN' | 'en-NZ' | 'en-US' | 'en-ZA' | 'en-ZM' | 'es-ES' | 'fa-AF' | 'fa-IR' | 'fr-FR' | 'he' | 'hu-HU' | 'id-ID' | 'it-IT' | 'ku-IQ' | 'nb-NO' | 'nl-NL' | 'nn-NO' | 'pl-PL' | 'pt-BR' | 'pt-PT' | 'ru-RU' | 'sk-SK' | 'sl-SI' | 'sr-RS' | 'sr-RS@latin' | 'sv-SE' | 'th-TH' | 'tr-TR' | 'uk-UA' | 'vi-VN'.

The second parameter is the object IsAlphaOptions. It only contains an optional parameter 'ignore', and it can have the value of a string, string[] or RegExp.
So you can also ignore white spaces with the RegExp \s.

```
.isAlpha('en-US', {ignore: '\s'})
```

Answer (score 1):

Hopefully Im not late to the party.
With class-validator@0.13.2, we can use

```
@Matches(/^[a-zA-Z0-9 -]*$/)
```

Just tweak the regex to satisfy your needs. In my case, I want to use @IsAlphanumeric() but with spaces and hyphen/dash

Answer (score 0):

To check, using express-validator, a string contains only letters and spaces you can use a regular expression

```
check('name').custom((value) => {
            return value.match(/^[A-Za-z ]+$/);
          })
```

Answer (score 0):

"john doe" consisting white space " ". Due to this white-space isAlpha() throwing error. isAlpha allows only a-zA-Z.

Answer (score -1):

Simply replace `isAlpha()` or `isAlphaNumeric()`

with

`isAlphanumericWithSpace()`/ `isAlphaWithSpace()`.

Comment: class-validator does not offere isAlphanumericWithSpace() decorator